# Calculate average time difference between multiple unix timestamps

Tags: php, timestamp, average, date-difference

i feel a little bit stupid, but let's imagine, that i have a set of unix timestamps:

```
1375110404
1374660925
1374482694
1374242337
1373793867
1373632889
1373187141
1373021668
1372754021
1372599890
```

What i'm trying to achieve is simple: I just want to calculate the average time difference between these 10 timestamps. I just can't find the proper way for the calculation.

What i just tried was

```
1375110404 - 1374660925 = 449479
1374482694 - 1374242337 = 240357
1373793867 - 1373632889 = 160978
1373187141 - 1373021668 = 165473
1372754021 - 1372599890 = 154131

449479 + 240357 + 160978 + 165473 + 154131 = 1170418

1170418 / 5 = 234083,6
```

but that looks illogical to me. Any advice is greatly appreciated.

EDIT:

All these stamps come from a php array.

EDIT:

Thanks to Orangepill for pointing me to the right direction. Here's the final solution:

```
for($cnt = count($array), $res = 0, $i = 1; $i < $cnt; $i++) {
    $res += $array[$i-1] - $array[$i];
}

echo $res/$cnt;
```

This calculates

```
1375110404 - 1374660925 = 449479
1374660925 - 1374482694 = 178231
1374482694 - 1374242337 = 240357
1374242337 - 1373793867 = 448470
1373793867 - 1373632889 = 160978
1373632889 - 1373187141 = 445748
1373187141 - 1373021668 = 165473
1373021668 - 1372754021 = 267647
1372754021 - 1372599890 = 154131

449479 + 178231 + 240357 + 448470 + 160978 + 445748 + 165473 + 267647 + 154131 = 2510514

2510514 / 10 = 251051.4
```

which looks correct to me.

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: The average time (in seconds) between all the timestamps. With an expectation of the result, i wouldn't ask for a solution ;)

Comment: *but that looks illogical to me.* -- are you trying to convert the above logic into PHP code, or are you saying the result is different from what you thought it would be?

Comment: are you only comparing adjacent times? i.e. t1-t2, t3-t4, t5-t6 ...  or do you need to compare to total differences? i.e. t1-t2, t1-t3, t1-t4 ...

Comment: Average = mean? median? mode?

Comment: No clue how to explain it different than above, sorry :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most straight forward way it to do it like you described.

```
 $res =0;
 for($x = 1, $num = count($array); $x < $num; $x++){
     $res =+ $array[$x] - $array[$x-1];
 }
 echo $res/($num-1);
```

Comment: This looks right to me, however i'll have to check, if that's exactly what i'm looking for. If yes, my theory was correct. Ty.

Comment: $res += $array[$x] - $array[$x-1];

Answer (score 1):

The [current accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18189669/212940) will give incorrect results if the the timestamps are not in strict chronological order. That is, negative values will skew your average. I may be wrong, but I imagine that you don't want to count any time difference as a negative value, after all, you can't run 100m in -12 seconds!

I provide this answer as an alternative that will always give an average based on positive time differences regardless of the order of the times in the passed array:-

```
function array_average_diff(array $array)
{
    $diff = 0;
    for($i = 1; $i < count($array); $i++){
        $diff += abs($array[$i] - $array[$i - 1]);
    }
    return $diff/count($array);
}
```

[See it working](http://3v4l.org/sOIHa)